# 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When run produces this on the console, can you fix it?

````
import feedparser
import discord
import asyncio

url = 'http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/feed/'

Client = discord.Client()
global last_id
last_id = []

#---Edit this before running the bot------
#1] Add the App Bot User Token you got from discord here
token = ...
#2] Add the Discord Channel IDs to which the bot will message when CSGO updates .
#bot has to be a part of the group to which the channel belongs . duh
channel_id = ['496709417203662848', '496709455816294411', '496709586196365323']

async def print_console(text):
    await Client.wait_until_ready()
    print(text)
    for num in channel_id:
        await Client.send_message(Client.get_channel(num),text)

@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    await Client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='CSGO-Updates'))
    print('Logged in as')
    print(Client.user.name)
    print(Client.user.id)
    print('------')

@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!check'):
        await Client.send_message(message.channel,'bot Running')
    if message.content.startswith('!help'):
        help_msg = '***the currently active commands are:***\n ```css\n{}\n``` \n'
        text = ' !help : displays the help documentation\n !check : checks if the bot is running,returns 0 or no message if bot is having problems\n !madeby : Steam URL of the bot Creator \n '
        await Client.send_message(message.channel, help_msg.format(text))
    if message.content.startswith('!madeby'):
        msg = ' *made by:* \n http://steamcommunity.com/id/zero_aak'
        await Client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

async def main():
    global last_id
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for index in feed.entries:
        last_id.append(index.id)
    print('primary scan complete')
    await print_console('bot started , use !help for help')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        feed = feedparser.parse(url)
        for item in feed.entries:
            if item.id not in last_id:
                last_id.append(item.id)
                await print_console(item.link)

Client.loop.create_task(main())
Client.run(token)
````

Here's what displays in the console:

```
C:\Users\FeNka\Downloads\Discord-CSGO-Update-bot-master\Discord-CSGO-Update-bot-master>python bot.py
primary scan complete
bot started , use !help for help
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<main() done, defined at bot.py:44> exception=AttributeError("'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 50, in main
    await print_console('bot started , use !help for help')
  File "bot.py", line 22, in print_console
    await Client.send_message(Client.get_channel(num),text)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 225, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 26, in on_ready
    await Client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='CSGO-Updates'))
TypeError: change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'game'
```

If need be, here is a guide to running it yourself:

1. Install Python if you don't already have it (recommended version 3.6+)
2. Make a new app on Discord here: 
   https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me
3. Add a bot user to the app and save the token for later use.
4. Get the client ID of the app
5. Use this link to add the bot to the server, replace the CLIENT_ID in the URL with the client ID you got:
   https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=bot&permissions=0
6. Enable developer mode in User Settings -> Appearance -> Enable Developer Mode.
7. Get the channel id by right clicking a channel , save it for later use.
8. Open bot.py in notepad and edit in the bot token and channel-id in the given spots.
9. Execute bot.py in python.
10. There you go, it's done. Use `!help` to see if the bot is running or not :)

**Commands:**

```
!help : displays the help dialogue
!check : checks if the bot is running or not 
!madeby : get my steam profile url to contact me
```

Comment: What version of discord.py are you uring?  `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`

Comment: Discord.py is worth the most the latest

Comment: Something is wrong with your discord library, because it does not match neither its current api documentation nor what your code is. Exactly what does it print out when you run @PatrickHaugh 's code?

Comment: I think you might be on the experimental rewrite branch, but if so you'll have to chnage much of the rest of your code, as the rewrite drastically altered several things you're relying on.  See [`change_presence`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence) in the rewrite documentation. Try `Client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='CSGO-Updates'))`

Comment: Most likely the problem is that since the discord.Client object does not a have send_message method.Could you solve the problem?

Comment: Indeed, the code has many discrepancies with your documentation...very very old

Comment: What can I do here what had worked?@PatrickHaugh 's

wait Client.send_message(Client.get_channel(num),text)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Comment: You can either run it on the version it was developed for by downgrading to the latest `0.16` release of discord.py (the "async" branch), or you can [update the code to rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html).  Instead of `Client.send_message(channel, text)` you use `channel.send(text)`.  Also ids are integers in rewrite.

Comment: how can I find the old version?

Comment: `pip uninstall discord.py` then `pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

You probably are on discord.py rewrite. Do this:

```
import discord
print(discord.__version__)
```

If it comes up with 1.0.0a you are rewrite, 0.16.0 is async.

Answer (score 0):

To help you, I need to know the version of discord.py you are using. You can try:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="CSGO-Updates"))
```

Just do

```
import discord
print(discord.__version__)
```